# Disabling hover Method

Tags: javascript, css, html, rickshaw

I am using Rickshaw javascript framework. Where there is one hover class is there. There I can modify the hover class to return my own result in the existing code.. In the same way I want to disable the hover to make the particular data visible without hovering. Is there any way to do that using CSS or javascript?

```
var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
            graph : graph,
            formatter : function(series, x, y) {
                var date = "Last Updated :" + '<br>' + '<span class="date">' + new Date(x * 1000).toUTCString() + '</span>';
                var swatch = '<span class="detail_swatch" style="background-color: ' + series.color + '"></span>';
                var content = swatch + mName[0] + '<br>' + "Average Price:" + "$" + parseInt(y) + '<br>' + "34 Products Included" + '<br>' + date;
                return content;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking the display property in the CSS controlling the graph? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp